# h2o.xgboost - no GPUs, no multithreading

Tags: h2o, xgboost

I wanted to add this as a comment to this question - [is multi-cpu supported by h2o-xgboost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523998/is-multi-cpu-supported-by-h2o-xgboost) - but apparently my rep is too low.

I am using the latest stable version of h2o (3.14.06).

In order to try and solve this problem i've made sure that gcc is built within my docker image (using apt-get install gcc)

```
    dpkg -l | grep gcc
    gcc              4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1       amd64 GNU C compiler
    gcc-5            5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5 amd64 GNU C compiler
    **output truncated**
```

Unfortunately when the cluster is spun up its still reporting:

```
    INFO: Found XGBoost backend with library: xgboost4j
    INFO: Your system supports only minimal version of XGBoost (no GPUs, no multithreading)!
```

Can anyone provide any insights? Clearly I'm missing a piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 2):

Right now H2O bundles only GPU-enabled and minimal (no GPU, no OMP) version of XGBoost. However, there is an experimental change in branch `mm/xgb_upgrade` which contains OMP-enabled version of XGBoost (instead of minimal version): https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/tree/mm/xgb_upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Building the mm/xgb_upgrade works. Which jira ticket is referring to this issue?